# CPU cores remain offline after hotplug

Tags: debian, cpu, kernel, ups, hotplug

When my UPS triggers an "on-battery" event, I want all cores to switch off to conserve power. The PC has 8 cores on two chips, UPS batteries need replacement every 3 months because of high current peaks. To alleviate my cost of ownership the following instructions are executed when the UPS fires such event:

```
for c in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/online; do
    echo 0 >$c
done
```

Cores 1 to 7 are successfully set offline while core 0 remains up, as expected.
Then `lscpu` and `atop` confirm that only cpu 0 remains online, and as a further indicator, the cpu temperatures fall from 90°C to 60°C.

When grid power comes back, the inverse command is executed:

```
for c in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/online; do
    echo 1 >$c
done
```

but the cores don't come online. At this point, `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/online` prints `1` for every cpu from 0 to 7, and `lscpu` reports that all cpus have returned online, but all my threads apparently continue to run exclusively on core 0, `atop` still lists only one core, and the system load remains bounded at about 100% rather than 800% as it normally does. Also, the cpu temperatures remain steady at 60°C.

Anomalously, while `top` lists the per-process cpu usage as percentages, these individual percentages sum up to about 100%, while the 60-seconds load average reported by `top` is a steady 8.

---

**Attributes:**

- Linux 4.1.1
- Debian 8
- LXC in active use
- KVM module loaded, not in active use
- CPU constantly loaded with over 8 runnable threads

---

**Update:**

I updated the kernel from 4.1.1 to 4.5.4. After testing, the same defect is still present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a known bug in LXC regarding the `cpuset` cgroup.
A few workarounds are described here: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=824519 .